# Error installing Solc when running Brownie

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, solidity

When I run the following command on windows visual code terminal to test my code

> brownie run scripts/file.py --network kovan

I get this error

> "SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output."

Also some errors referring to files for running the installation but so far my trouble shooting has led me to uninstall brownie then install with pipx and initialized a package.json and ran

> npm install -g solc

and i still get that error whenever I run the script

Answer (score 0):

### Install Solc on Windows

1. Download the Windows binary from
   https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases
2. Put the solc-windows.exe into a new folder
3. Rename solc-windows.exe to solc.exe
4. Launch a command prompt and cd into the directory where solc.exe was
   extracted to

   First check the version

   ```
   solc --version
   ```

In your case I recommend adding it to you PATH variable:

1. Click Start and type system. From the search results select System
   (Control Panel)
2. Start System
3. From the System window on the left click Advanced system settings
4. On the Advanced tab click Environmental variables
5. Under User variables for… select Path and click Edit
6. Add the path to your solc installation, then click OK, OK, and OK to
   save. Close and reopen any command prompts for the change to be
   reflected.

Credits: https://www.codeooze.com/blockchain/solc-hello-world/

Comment: where would solc have been extracted too?

Comment: wherever you want, its important that you put that path in the Environment variable after

Comment: so should i save it around programs so i can run different scripts?

Comment: yeah sure you can

Comment: so i extracted to program files and went to the dir and solc --version errors saying it doesnt exist I cd to C:\Program Files\solidity-0.8.4> and ran it

Comment: you need to rename solc-windows.exe to solc.exe

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/download/v0.8.4/solc-windows.exe

Comment: You downloaded the source code, not the executable download solc-windows.exe

Comment: downloaded source code again and that file doesnt exist in that dir sothing with solc .exe but where do i add that solc-windows too?

Comment: No man, you dont need the source code, you just need the executable

Comment: got it to run version and added path ran the brownie command now and it started and gave the output -> Generating interface ABIs...
Downloading from https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/windows-amd64/solc-windows-amd64-v0.4.26+commit.4563c3fc.zip -> then the solc error again

Comment: check if the solc command is callable from cmd in any directory

Comment: can call it still but im in the project file when i call it i deleted a file called solx in a diff directory and now it keeps trying to install version 0.6.12 and giving an error how can i skip this and just run my script?

Comment: No because it needs the specific version of solc, I suggest you use remix ide https://remix.ethereum.org/

Comment: i want to use these values with for a python or js file will remix let me or is there any way to use a script relying on other versions?

Comment: I cant understand